# Checking a Scala Promise for Success

Tags: scala, promise

Is this a good approach to check the value in a Promise for success?

```
def isPromiseSuccess[T](promise: Promise[T]): Boolean =
  promise.future.value.isDefined && promise.future.value.get.isSuccess
```

Even though it is guarded, I hate using get on the containers (Option, Try) etc., Is there a better approach? Any suggestions?

Comment: A good approach would be to use the callbacks to unwrap it rather than calling `.get` most of the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.exists` to check whether the value of the `Future` (a) is defined and (b) is a `Success`:

```
def isPromiseSuccess[T](promise: Promise[T]): Boolean = {
  promise.future.value.exists(_.isSuccess)
}
```